# WordPress redirect full site to HTTPS and then add redirect rule for one page to HTTP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

After a long R&D process, I am here with an unresolved issue of WordPress redirection. None of the available resources helped me really.

What I need is -

I have successfully redirected my entire WP site and admin to HTTPS.

Now, I need one specific page to redirect to HTTP only. Because I will be using iframe on that page to load external sites for preview.

My requested url should be like this -

http://example.com/live-preview/?product_id=(number like 1,2,3 etc)

I want the above url(s) to load without HTTPS.

My present htaccess file is this -

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

So anything with (/live-preview/) should be on HTTP only. Please help me how I will be able to do this.

Thank you so much.
-Amit

Comment: I am still trying to resolve this issue. My latest rewrite code is -

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^live-preview [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^live-preview [NC]
RewriteRule http://%{SERVER_NAME}/live-preview/$1 [R=301,L]`

But no luck! Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: No one can help me really?

Answer (score 0):

After a long investment of time and many researches, I manage to fix this issue with my code. I am sharing this for public interest.

This is the working htaccess code -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^product_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So I have to use `{QUERY_STRING}` and use 2 conditions with 301 permanent redirection.